# How to make heroku clone from github recursively to get my submodule?

Tags: git, heroku

I used heroku's web page to set up my discord bot app. Every time after I push to my github's master branch, heroku will automatically deploy to heroku. Now I have created another branch called "dev-NoUser" and added a submodule (my other repo) into this repo. I want to deploy this branch to heroku, so I select the branch under the drop down list in name_of_my_app/Deploy/Automatic_deploys. However, heroku didn't clone my submodule. What should I do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

GitHub Sync on Heroku doesn't do an actual `git push`. So it doesn't fetch submodules automatically.
You can resolve this with a custom buildpack: https://github.com/dmathieu/heroku-buildpack-submodules

```
heroku buildpacks:add https://github.com/dmathieu/heroku-buildpack-submodules -i 1
```

Comment: Thank you! It works! But heroku ask me to add `-a <my app name>` to your command. I'm new to heroku, could you tell me what's that -i 0 meaning?

Comment: Try `heroku help buildpacks:add` ;-)

Comment: this still does not work for me because on github sync or push to heroku git the .gitmodules file is removed

Comment: You probably have another issue, because Heroku doesn't remove the `.gitmodules` file. You should make sure it's properly within your GIT repository.