# Git clone doesn't auto-clone submodules, causes issues with heroku auto deploy

Tags: git, heroku, git-submodules

I have a git repo with a submodule in it which I would like to deploy to heroku on an auto-deployed pipeline, but when the `ng build --prod` process is near completion I get the error

```
ERROR in : Couldn't resolve resource ./repo/style.css relative to /tmp/build_d3089108a84fd9e7fb117fed84b787b6/src/app/resume/resume.component.ts
```

because my submodule (which exists at `/src/app/resume/repo`) is referenced in the file `resume.component.ts`:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-resume',
  templateUrl: './repo/resume.html',
  styleUrls: ['./repo/style.css']
})
```

and although the github repo points to a specific commit for the submodule, the initial git clone does not clone the submodule alongside it.

My `.gitmodules` file is as follows:

```
[submodule "Resume"]
    path = src/app/resume/repo
    url = https://github.com/<my username>/Resume.git
```

### Question:

Is there a way to force heroku-git to clone submodules at the same time as the full repo?

Can I run a script that makes heroku clone the submodule on its own after cloning the full repo **but before** building?

Comment: It [should just work](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/git-submodules#git-submodules). Are you sure you have a proper `.gitmodules` file? (Submodules aren't just nested repos; the [containing repo should have a `.gitmodules` file](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules#_starting_submodules).)

Comment: I have a .gitmodules file set up, I'll add it to the post. And the repo is public

Comment: Are there any filename casing differences, e.g. `resume` vs. `Resume`? This would work on Windows and maybe macOS, but not on Heroku.

Comment: The first letter of the repo name is capitalized and everything else is lowercase.

Comment: Try `clone` with the recurse-submodules or recursive option (I forget which)

Comment: On my local machine this fixes it, but if I want heroku to pull submodules I have to use the answer from @VonC below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only issue with using GitHub repo submodules on Heroku would be:

- through GitHub Sync (where you [must use a custom buildpack](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53370541/6309))
- with GitHub 2FA activated (you could [declare your submodule URLs using a PAT, Personal Access Token](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41265115/6309), but the [scope would be read/write](https://developer.github.com/apps/building-oauth-apps/understanding-scopes-for-oauth-apps/), as [explained here](https://github.com/jollygoodcode/jollygoodcode.github.io/issues/6))

Comment: Yep, that custom buildpack trick fixed it. Setting https://github.com/dmathieu/heroku-buildpack-submodules as the first buildpack forced heroku to pull the complete submodule and the build succeeded